# How to make Ubuntu VM in VirtualBox accessible from the internet?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu server in VirtualBox.

The host is Windows 7 x64.

[image]

The guest is Ubuntu 11.10 x64.

I want to make this server accessible from the internet. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you already access the Ubuntu server from your host OS? What are your IP settings for both host and guest? Which services do you want to make accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is largely depending on how you set the networking for your VM. If you have set it to NAT, you will have to configure [port forwarding](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward) in VirtualBox.
If you have set it to Bridged, you will have to set up routing between the VirtualBox networking adapter and your physical network adapter. But that shouldn't be a VirtualBox-specific issue.

Comment: Wind 7 machine has external ip. img687.imageshack.us/img687/1184/20120127225619.png but when I try to bridge it, guest os - ubuntu doesn't detect network at all

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu Sadly, I'm having issues with VirtualBox right now myself (won't start). Without being able to verify my assumptions, I can't be of any help.